# Mongodb shell JavaScript read a different table

Tags: javascript, mongodb, printing

when using Robomongo and localhost when I sent the query
db.getCollection('q2').find({}) I get the expected answer.
However when I attempt to write a shell script and use 
dev a = db.getCollection('q2').find({});

a is a object that looks like a setting table. Any Ideas?

Comment: `a` is actually a [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) to the documents that match the query criteria. When the `find()` method “returns documents,” the method is actually returning a cursor to the documents. In the mongo shell, when you assign the cursor returned from the `find()` method to a variable using the var keyword like what you have done, the cursor does not automatically iterate. You can [manually iterate the cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#manually-iterate-the-cursor) using `next()`, `forEach()` or `toArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [db.collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

as `db.q2.find()`.

Hope this helps.